# Make CABasicAnimation for iOS Running Multiple Times

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I'm building an app that will have an animation of one image "walking" across the screen, using simple CABasicAnimation.  I have it set for it to walk a certain distance in a duration, and then stop until the user gives it more commands, in which it will continue walking for the same distance and duration again.  The issue that I have is that after the first time, the image will stop where it should, but it won't continue to walk, it will jump back to its original spot and start over.  I thought I had this set correctly on the origin point, but I guess not.

```
CABasicAnimation *hover = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    hover.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    hover.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    hover.additive = YES; // fromValue and toValue will be relative instead of absolute values
    hover.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero];
    hover.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(110.0, -50.0)]; // y increases downwards on iOS
    hover.autoreverses = FALSE; // Animate back to normal afterwards
    hover.duration = 10.0; // The duration for one part of the animation (0.2 up and 0.2 down)
    hover.repeatCount = 0; // The number of times the animation should repeat
    [theDude.layer addAnimation:hover forKey:@"myHoverAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your from value is set to be zero and it's not being updated.

```
hover.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero];
```

You have to update this value with your to value each time.

Here I've put your code in a function where you can update starting and ending points.

```
- (void)moveFromPoint:(CGPoint)fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)toPoint {
    CABasicAnimation *hover = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    hover.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    hover.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    hover.additive = YES; // fromValue and toValue will be relative instead of absolute values
    hover.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:fromPoint];
    hover.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toPoint]; // y increases downwards on iOS
    hover.autoreverses = FALSE; // Animate back to normal afterwards
    hover.duration = 10.0; // The duration for one part of the animation (0.2 up and 0.2 down)
    hover.repeatCount = 0; // The number of times the animation should repeat
    [theDude.layer addAnimation:hover forKey:@"myHoverAnimation"];
}
```

You can move the guy further by calling this function with new points each time.

```
[self moveFromPoint:CGPointZero toPoint:CGPointMake(110.0, -50.0)]

[self moveFromPoint:CGPointMake(110.0, -50.0) toPoint:CGPointMake(160.0, -50.0)]
```

**EDIT:**

I see that you want to move the guy with the same ratio but in different lenght each time.

Add this variable just after the @interface:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint oldPointOfTheGuy;
```

And add this new function just after the previous function:

```
- (void)moveByDistance:(CGFloat)distance {
    CGPoint newPointOfTheGuy = CGPointMake(self.oldPointOfTheGuy.x + 2.2*distance, self.oldPointOfTheGuy.y + distance);
    [self moveFromPoint:self.oldPointOfTheGuy toPoint:newPointOfTheGuy];
    self.oldPointOfTheGuy = newPointOfTheGuy;
}
```

And set a starting point for the guy in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.oldPointOfTheGuy = CGPointMake(110.0, -50)
```

Now we have set the old position of the guy as where we know he spawns for the first time.

From now on, each time we want to move him, we will call this:

```
[self moveByDistance:20];
```

What this function does is, since that it already knows your x / y ratio which is 2.2, it just adds 20 to your old y position and adds 2.2 * 20 to your old x position. And each time a new position is set, old position is updated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like where this is going, but as there is some user interaction, he may not always move the same distance each time, I may have typed out that part wrong in my OP.  The ratio/slope would stay constant, just not the entire distance.  Any recommendation on where to go with that?

Comment: Works great.  One last question I have with this.  Is there a way that the animation will always run normal, but if he gets to a certain point on the screen, have a different animation happen?  It's something that it may never get to that point, but if he does, do this?

Comment: Some functions in iOS have their callbacks. Like when they finish, they tell you they've been finished. If this one had it, you could know that animation is finished on a certain point and start a new animation on that exact time. However this one doesn't have such a callback. What it does have is duration. You know your animation will end in 10 miliseconds for example. So you could call another one after 10 ms. However all of these are wrong paths. This is why game engines are made like Unity or SpriteKit of iOS. If you want to make a game, these would be your best shots.

Comment: Otherwise you would have to spend really too much time to control animations. You would have to setup a frame mechanism where you call certain functions every millisecond, where you can check for current position of your guy every millisecond. This way you could know where he is in exact given time and call another animation if necessarry. However those are all long shots.